# Whats the route a ping packet takes

Tags: networking

Lets say I have 2 pc's connected to a router. oNe of them is wireless and the other is wired. Not really sure if it makes difference here in thi question. I can ping 1 pc from another. But when I do a tracert I see that it talks directly to each other without the router as a gateway. As far as I knew I though all communication has to go through the router? Then how do do pc's ping each other directly?

Comment: It is how you have configured your network, especially your router's settings.

Comment: please paste the output that leads you to your conclusion. If I ping another computer and tracert another computer, neither show me that it went through the router, though it must have because the computers are not connected directly.

Comment: Switches are Ethernet devices, invisible at the IP layer. Your router is also a switch. It routes *between* networks but switches *within* the LAN.

Comment: The reason why I was confused is this. I have a virtual tun0 interface and I have specified ip forwarding as on. So lets the the ipv6 address of the interface is aaaa::bbbb/64 with a 64 bit prefix. When I ping it from another computer how does it know where it has to enter and to which computer the ping goes to? Because there will be no response to the ARP message since there is no MAC address for the virtual interface. But I can still see the packet being forwarded. So how exactly does this work?

Answer (score 0):

While your router functions as an IP (network layer) router, it also functions as an ethernet switch (data link layer). Network layer messages are always wrapped inside of data link layer messages.

Any host connected directly to your switch can contact any other directly connected host via the data link layer by specifying the MAC address of the receiver when sending. A sending host discovers the MAC address using Address Resolution Protocol (ARP). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol for more information.

The flow basically goes like this:

The sender (say 192.168.1.10) wants to send to a receiver (say 192.168.1.11). The sender knows that the receiver is on the same subnet because of the network mask (255.255.255.0). The sender sends a broadcast ARP message (which goes to all hosts on the local network via the data link layer) requesting an answer for 192.168.1.11. The recipient host will respond with its MAC address. Now that the sender knows the recipient's MAC address, it creates an IP packet and sends it directly to the recipient by specifying the recipient's MAC address at the data link layer.

Since the MAC address of the recipient is specified, the switch doesn't need to do any IP (network layer) routing; it simply performs data link layer switching by sending the packets to the right MAC address. The packet going from wired to wireless is largely irrelevant at the data link layer - those are physical layer concerns, and the data link layer sits on top of the physical layer.

Therefore, as far as the network layer is concerned (which ping concerns itself with), the packet goes directly from the sender to the recipient. As far as the data link layer is concerned, the packet is switched from one link to another by the switch.

Note that the actual flow is a bit more complicated; MAC addresses are cached, for example, but in general it works as described.

Comment: "data link layer routing by sending the packets to the right MAC address"- What exactly does the router do then? Does it forward it to the correct port on the router since there are many ethernet jacks?(I may be completely wrong here, but right now I am confused).

Comment: Switching at the data link layer is concerned with physically sending a packet down the right link (e.g. an ethernet cable). Your switch knows the MAC address of every device connected to it along with the corresponding ethernet jack (or wireless frequencies). Therefore, if a packet contains a MAC address, the switch knows where to send it.

Answer (score 0):

They don't ping each other directly, it went through the router.

They can only ping each other directly if they are connected directly.

Here's an example from my network

They went through the so-called "home/Nat router", the switch within the device, though the output isn't showing you that

```
C:\Users\user1>ping acomp

Pinging acomp.lan [192.168.1.66] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.66: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.1.66: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.1.66: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.1.66: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.66:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

C:\Users\user1>tracert acomp

Tracing route to acomp.lan [192.168.1.66]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  acomp.lan [192.168.1.66]

Trace complete.

C:\Users\user1>
```

Really though you should include a paste of some output from your ping and tracert that led you to your conclusion

Comment: The tracert is the reason I concluded that it is not going thorugh the router. if there is anything else you need me to add please do let me know

Comment: The so-called Router you have isn't Routing it. Routing is a process where you take a packet, see the IP at the destination, look up where to send it.  The switch within the device you have, uses the MAC address, this is not routing. Tracert only shows the route when routing is going on it shows the path and all routers it has gone through to the destination. Your NAT Router, Home Router, your so-called router. Your device you call a router, is not routing in this case. Your NAT Router is only routing when it goes from LAN to WAN.

Comment: Your device is like a Router with 2 sockets one WAN one LAN and a switch connected to the LAN socket. And so it's not even reaching any routing functionality.

Comment: Your computers and devices have 2 addresses. An IP Address and a MAC address. Routing decides on the destination based on IP addresses. Switches use MAC Addresses. Open cmd.exe type  C:\>arp -a <Return>.  See those MAC addresses corresponding to IP addresses. The switch is using the MAC Address to decide where to send the "packet", not the IP Address. When it's for the Router, then you get the destination IP of the destination computer and the MAC Address of the Router.

Comment: @madman  a switch only has an IP and MAC for management, and a switch within a "router" wouldn't even have that.  So yeah it's going to the device you call a Router, but it's not Routing. The MAC address is of the dest computer not the router. That's why tracert doesn't show it going through a router. Obviously it's not going directly from one comp to another 'cos the computers aren't connected directly. It's going through the switch in that device you call a router.

Comment: The reason why I was confused is this. I have a virtual tun0 interface and I have specified ip forwarding as on. So lets the the ipv6 address of the interface is aaaa::bbbb/64 with a 64 bit prefix. When I ping it from another computer how does it know where it has to enter and to which computer the ping goes to? Because there will be no response to the ARP message since there is no MAC address for the virtual interface. But I can still see the packet being forwarded. So how exactly does this work?

Comment: @madman  I don't use IPv6 myself, and haven't any virtual machines in front of me, but I suppose a virtual machine could have a MAC address, I see "mac address of virtual interface" gives some google results. As to ARP and iPv6, one can read here, that IPv6 doesn't use ARP. http://keepingitclassless.net/2011/10/neighbor-solicitation-ipv6s-replacement-for-arp/   it uses "neighbour solicitation". that guy sniffs it with wireshark.